# Yii CDbCriteria

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii

Hollow i have kind of query for my table `select m.voterID, sum(jm.mark) from marks m
left join marks jm on jm.id = m.id
where jm.voterID in (1,2)
group by m.voterID`

and i don't understand how to wright it using the CDbCriteria. 
table structute is

```
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `voterId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `votedId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mark` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `creation_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Comment: You table structure have two columns with name voterId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select = 'm.voterID, sum(jm.mark)';
$criteria->from = 'marks m';
$criteria->join = 'left join marks jm on jm.id = m.id';
$criteria->condition = 'jm.voterID in (1,2)';
$criteria->group = 'm.voterID';
```